# About JavaScript prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm learning javascript prototype,but I come across a problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Person(){}
        Person.prototype.name="aa";
        Person.prototype.sayName=function(){
            alert(this.name);
        }
        var person1=new Person();
        person1.name="bb";
        alert(person1.sayName());
    </script>
```

why it returns 2 results."bb"and undefined?

Comment: Where do you get _undefined_?

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have created object of person and in that you are setting 
 of 
name property as "bb" and in the function you are doing alert of sayname which is not a property, its a function

**detailed explanation:**
this is your factory object i.e your function definition

```
function Person(){}
        Person.prototype.name="aa";
        Person.prototype.sayName=function(){
            alert(this.name);
        }
```

*Now you create an instance of object to use its properties and function*

```
var per = new Person();
```

*Now using per you can overwrite that property or you can call function*

```
per.name = "bb";
```

*the above code will set property name == "bb" so in alert you will get bb to access sayName you should use*

```
per.sayName();
```

*this will give you output "bb"*

*into the sayName function the alert will give bb because this refers to the object and then it will look for property.name*

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the prototype and the properties, everything is working as expected. The problem is that `person1.sayName()` does not `return` anything, so it implicitly **returns `undefined`**, and that's what the `alert(…)` will print.

You want only one alert, so you should use either

```
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
    return this.name;
};
…
alert(person1.sayName());
```

or

```
Person.prototype.sayName = function() {
    alert(this.name);
};
…
person1.sayName();
```